# Execute specific code when specific button is click one it

Tags: php, javascript, shell, button

I have problem to only execute one of the script at a time when one of the button is click. The code execute 2 script together when the button is click. How can I only execute one script at a time and specific button execute specific script. Thanks for the help. Below is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function popup(){
        window.location = 'testing.php?run=shell';
    }
    function popdown(){
        window.location = 'testing.php?run=shell';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="popup()" value="popup">
<?php
if(isset($_GET['run']) && ($_GET['run'] == 'shell')){
    echo shell_exec('sh bash_test.sh');
}
?>
<input type="button" onclick="popdown()" value="popdown">
<?php
if(isset($_GET['run']) && ($_GET['run'] == 'shell')){
    echo shell_exec('sh bash_run.sh');
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function popup(){
        window.location = 'testing.php?run=test';
    }
    function popdown(){
        window.location = 'testing.php?run=run';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="popup()" value="popup">
<?php
if(isset($_GET['run']) && ($_GET['run'] == 'test')){
    echo shell_exec('sh bash_test.sh');
}
?>
<input type="button" onclick="popdown()" value="popdown">
<?php
if(isset($_GET['run']) && ($_GET['run'] == 'run')){
    echo shell_exec('sh bash_run.sh');
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just mark the scripts separately

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function popup(){
        window.location = 'testing.php?run=shell1';
    }
    function popdown(){
        window.location = 'testing.php?run=shell2';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="popup()" value="popup">
<?php
if(isset($_GET['run']) && ($_GET['run'] == 'shell1')){
    echo shell_exec('sh bash_test.sh');
}
?>
<input type="button" onclick="popdown()" value="popdown">
<?php
if(isset($_GET['run']) && ($_GET['run'] == 'shell2')){
    echo shell_exec('sh bash_run.sh');
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```